# Data is not being summed properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query that I can't get to sum properly.

First step

```
SELECT DISTINCT
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
,SUM(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt) as Expiring

--,CASE WHEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt > det.ordd_mn_billed_amt
--THEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt - det.ordd_mn_billed_amt
--ELSE 0
--END AS Upsell

FROM ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_ord o
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet det ON o.id = det.ordd_id
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.ContractItem CI ON CI.ContractItemID = det.ordd_ContractItemID
WHERE 
--det.ordd_mn_billed_amt > 0
CI.ContractItemID =327
AND det.ordd_mn_end_date BETWEEN '05/31/2020' AND '11/01/2020' --Expiring
GROUP BY 
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
--,det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt
--,det.ordd_mn_billed_amt

ORDER BY 
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
```

This works I will get 1 line of data
When I add the next case statement that is when I get issues

Second step

```
SELECT
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
,SUM(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt) as Expiring

,CASE WHEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt > det.ordd_mn_billed_amt
THEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt - det.ordd_mn_billed_amt
ELSE 0
END AS Upsell

FROM ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_ord o
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet det ON o.id = det.ordd_id
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.ContractItem CI ON CI.ContractItemID = det.ordd_ContractItemID
WHERE 
--det.ordd_mn_billed_amt > 0
CI.ContractItemID =327
AND det.ordd_mn_end_date BETWEEN '05/31/2020' AND '11/01/2020' --Expiring
GROUP BY 
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
,det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt
,det.ordd_mn_billed_amt

ORDER BY 
det.ordd_ContractItemID
,det.ordd_mn_start_date
,det.ordd_mn_end_date
,det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt
,det.ordd_mn_billed_amt
```

results

```
ordd_ContractItemID ordd_mn_start_date       ordd_mn_end_date          Expiring  Upsell
327                 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000  2020-09-30 00:00:00.000    0.00     0.00
327                 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000  2020-09-30 00:00:00.000    0.00     0.00
327                 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000  2020-09-30 00:00:00.000    0.00     0.00
327                 2017-10-01 00:00:00.000  2020-09-30 00:00:00.000    36331.86 0.00
```

I have also tried an IIF statement with the same duplicated results.

```
--,IIF(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt > det.ordd_mn_billed_amt,(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt - det.ordd_mn_billed_amt),0) AS Upsell
```

Comment: You are aggregating on `det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt` *and* grouping on it; if you want to aggregate something it shouldn't be in the `GROUP BY`. Also, in the first query you have both a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY`. That almost always means that either your `GROUP BY` is wrong, or the `DISTINCT` is superfluous and just adding unneeded overhead.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue. You gave us code and the result it gives, we don't know what you want to happen

Comment: What I want is to have one line of output instead of 4.

Comment: I have removed the Distinct from the select. If I remove --,det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt
--,det.ordd_mn_billed_amt from the group by and the order BY I get the invalid in the select list error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to evaluate cost vs profit. Try doing your summations in an inner select, then performing the CASE statement afterwards.

```
SELECT  ordd_ContractItemID
        ,ordd_mn_start_date
        ,ordd_mn_end_date
        ,t.Cost
        ,t.Profit
        ,CASE
             WHEN t.Cost > t.Profit THEN t.Cost - t.Profit
             ELSE 0
         END AS Upsell
FROM    (
            SELECT  det.ordd_ContractItemID
                    ,det.ordd_mn_start_date
                    ,det.ordd_mn_end_date
                    ,SUM(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt) AS Cost
                    ,SUM(det.ordd_mn_billed_amt) AS Profit
            FROM    dbo.lti_ord AS o
                    INNER JOIN dbo.lti_orddet AS det ON o.id = det.ordd_id
                    INNER JOIN dbo.ContractItem AS CI ON CI.ContractItemID = det.ordd_ContractItemID
            WHERE   1 = 1
                    AND CI.ContractItemID = 327
                    AND det.ordd_mn_end_date BETWEEN '05/31/2020' AND '11/01/2020'  --Expiring
            GROUP BY
                    det.ordd_ContractItemID
                    ,det.ordd_mn_start_date
                    ,det.ordd_mn_end_date
        ) AS t;
```

Comment: It has been awhile. How do I do that?

Comment: Click the checkmark button to the left of the answer :-)

Comment: You can use aggregates in a CASE.  You can also aggerate on a CASE.

Comment: That's not true either. https://rextester.com/ZABRN14916

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY has to be for the grouping you required.  Other columns go into aggregates one way or another.  For the total Upsell, SUM the Upsell from each record.  Maybe something like below.  Note that DISTINCT is not required because the GROUP BY is already distinct.

```
SELECT det.ordd_ContractItemID, 
    det.ordd_mn_start_date, 
    det.ordd_mn_end_date, 
    SUM(det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt) as [Expiring],
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt > det.ordd_mn_billed_amt 
                THEN det.ordd_mn_prev_paid_amt - det.ordd_mn_billed_amt 
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS [Upsell]
FROM ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_ord o
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.lti_orddet det 
ON o.id = det.ordd_id
INNER JOIN ccmast_restore_20201021.dbo.ContractItem CI 
ON CI.ContractItemID = det.ordd_ContractItemID
WHERE CI.ContractItemID = 327
    AND det.ordd_mn_end_date BETWEEN '05/31/2020' AND '11/01/2020' --Expiring
GROUP BY det.ordd_ContractItemID, 
    det.ordd_mn_start_date, 
    det.ordd_mn_end_date
ORDER BY det.ordd_ContractItemID, 
    det.ordd_mn_start_date, 
    det.ordd_mn_end_date
```